# ORA-00904: "TOTAL_ORDERS": invalid identifier

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm currently trying to count orders in each suburb that were delivered later than requested for a month and the average time by which they were late.

I've done this so far without the parameter query for the user to input the month they wish to see.

```
SELECT s.suburbname, 
        Count(*) AS total_orders ,
        ("ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED - "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME)/total_orders AS latetime
FROM   "ORDER" 
left join restaurant r 
       ON "ORDER".restaurantid = r.restaurantid 
left join suburb s 
       ON r.suburbid = s.suburbid  
       WHERE   "ORDER".deliveredflag = 'X' 
       AND "ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED >  "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME 
GROUP  BY s.suburbname 
ORDER  BY total_orders, latetime;
```

However it's throwing me a ORA-00904: "TOTAL_ORDERS": invalid identifier.

Is it my group by clause?

**Update 1** I've managed to solve it thank you everyone! However now I have a different problem. I can't seem to sum INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND Datatypes as it throws me the error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND.

Is there away to sum up all the difference in time and average it out?

**Update 2**

I've managed to solve all my problems by using the EXTRACT function to extract out the hours and minutes and summing all of them together against the count.

```
SELECT 

s.suburbname, 
       Count(*) AS total_orders,

SUM(60*(Extract(hour from "ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED) - Extract(hour from "ORDER".Custreqtime)) + Extract(minute from "ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED) - Extract(minute from "ORDER".Custreqtime))as amt


FROM   "ORDER" 
       left join restaurant r 
              ON "ORDER".restaurantid = r.restaurantid 
       left join suburb s 
              ON r.suburbid = s.suburbid 
WHERE  
"ORDER".deliveredflag = 'X'
AND
"ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED > "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME
GROUP  BY s.suburbname
ORDER  BY s.suburbname desc;
```

Comment: If you have a new question, you should work a little to find the answer by yourself, then ask a new one. Here is not how it works. You don't have a post for yourself to get support on Oracle syntax! You go get a book and learn first.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've managed to solve my problem highlighted in the update as well. Will post the solution for others. It may help them

Answer (score 2):

You cannot re-use `total_orders` in the calculation you do either:

```
 SELECT s.suburbname, Count(*) total_orders ,
("ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED - "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME)/count(*) latetime     
FROM   "ORDER" 
left join restaurant r 
...
```

Hope it helps

Comment: `AS` is legal syntax for column aliases (but not for table aliases).

Comment: @APC, thanks, my bad again. But can `total_orders` be used in the syntax of the calculation in the select?

Answer (score 2):

Problems are in this line `("ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED - "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME)/total_orders AS latetime`.

`Total_order` is only column alias defined in line before. And the second hidden exception is `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression.`

Probably you should use the analytical function in this query. But i don't know business requirement.

```
  select s.suburbname
       , count(*) over( partition by s.suburbname) as total_orders

       , ("ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED - "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME) /  count(*) over( partition by s.suburbname) as latetime
    from "ORDER"
         left join restaurant r on "ORDER".restaurantid = r.restaurantid
         left join suburb s on r.suburbid = s.suburbid
   where "ORDER".deliveredflag = 'X' and "ORDER".ACTUALTIMEDELIVERED > "ORDER".CUSTREQTIME
order by total_orders, latetime;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have solved the issue but now have difficulty adding up interval datatype values as added on in my question